# positioning an image on a custom position

Tags: positioning

I would like to know if it´s possible to position an image in a custom position. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}

\item $\overline{AD}$ y $\overline{CE}$ son alturas. Entonces el valor de $\alpha$ es: 

\begin{enumerate}[A)]
    \item $70^\circ$
    \item $90^\circ$
    \item $110^\circ$
\end{enumerate}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{anggn1.PNG}
\end{figure}


\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

This image illustrates my question. Thanks in advance :D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to do it with the `\InsertBoxR` command, from the plain TeX macros package `insbox`. This command uses 2 mandatory arguments: the number of unshortened lines in the following paragraph, and the contents of the box to be inserted. To have no problem with the list environment, I use the `rightmargin` key for the nested enumerate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{3}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\overline{AD}$ y $\overline{CE}$ son alturas. Entonces el valor de $\alpha$ es:
%
\begin{enumerate}[A), rightmargin=3.5cm]
    \item $70^\circ$ Blah blah blah. Blih blih blih. Blooh blooh blooh
    \item $90^\circ$
    \item $110^\circ$
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item $\overline{AD}$ y $\overline{CE}$ son alturas. Entonces el valor de $\alpha$ es: 

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[A)]
    \item $70^\circ$
    \item $90^\circ$
    \item $110^\circ$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\includegraphics[scale=0.25, valign=t]{anggn1.PNG}

\item Second item

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks :D, It look fine! But I don't know how to change the black box :o

Comment: Remove the demo option from the graphicx package.

Comment: Is it possible to use your technique with a table? I tried 
    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Edad} & \textbf{$f$} \\ \hline
$18$          & $7$          \\ \hline
$19$          & $6$          \\ \hline
$20$          & $5$          \\ \hline
$21$          & $3$          \\ \hline
$22$          & $2$          \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
But it does not work. Should I convert the table to an image to use this technique? Or there is another way?

Comment: I guess, the table is supposed to replace the image in the original example. If that assumption is correct, try without the `table` environment and without the `\centering` command. Using the optional argument of the `tabular` enviornment (as i `\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}`) could also help in order to improve the vertical alignment.